# How to write Mixin for queryset that returns only the data owned by the logged in user?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

How to write a generic Mixin for CBV so that the queryset returns only the data owned by the logged in user?

Is it possible in django?

If it is...Can somebody give me specific suggestions or answer of how to perform this in django...

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its like this

```
class MyMixin:

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(MyMixin, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

if you need something more flexible, you can do

```
class MyMixin:
    my_field = None
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(MyMixin, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(**{self.my_field=self.request.user})
```

and in every class than use the mixin you will need replace this for the field to the user as example

```
from django.db import models
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user_owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

then when you implement the mixin in a list view with the model MyModel. t

```
from django.views import generic

class MyModelListView(MyMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = MyModel
    my_field = "user_owner"
```

the var my_field must have the same name as the field in the model

Comment: Have tried this but its giving me another error 'Cannot resolve keyword 'owner' into field'...

Comment: well the owner is a example this must be replaced by you field in the django model

Comment: Great.It worked..Thank you very much...It was a real help

Comment: 'return qs.filter(**{self.my_field=self.request.user})' this line is giving me a error of invalid syntax...